# How to create an ipython alias for "import pandas as pd"?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, python-import

I would like ipython shell to `import pandas as pd` when I type `ip`. How to do it?

Comment: Check out [This Link](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html). Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: will typing ip() instead of ip to get the import statement work?

Comment: you may want to setup ipython "startup" scripts where you would automatically import all needed modules...

Comment: I tried to make it work with (magic) aliases, couldn't. I don't want () that come with a function call. And I don't want to add the import to the startup file.